# Clean BLE Bluetooth Cache or Buffer

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am doing a reading of a device, and when doing successive readings the information is not updated, so I would need to know how I could clean the cache or buffer that may be causing this information not to be updated. You are using the BLE module already implemented in the SDK that the device brings by calling the methods already defined in it.

Specifically it is a bracelet that captures the heart rate and as for the SDK does not bring documentation just a few examples. That calling the methods as indicated, after some synchronization returns the same data that occasionally refreshes again and sometimes not, I have also noticed that sometimes the data returned are wrong.

```
ProtocolUtils.getInstance().StartSyncHealthData();//Sync

@Override
public void onSysEvt(int evt_base, final int evt_type, int error, final int value) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(evt_type == ProtocolEvt.SYNC_EVT_HEALTH_PROGRESS.toIndex()){
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setTitle("Synchronization : " + value + "%");
        }
    }, 200);
}else if (evt_type == ProtocolEvt.SYNC_EVT_HEALTH_SYNC_COMPLETE.toIndex()) {//Synchronization is complete
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 200);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no cache or buffer, at least on the Android side. Why don't you use notifications instead? Then data is only sent when necessary.